# Rails relational models errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `has_many` relation in some model, and accept nested attributes for it. After not passed validation for this relation, all errors, that belongs to some attribute, stored in the same key of errors hash.

Part of request:

```
"values_attributes":[{"value":"","attribute_id":1,"id":1,"auction_id":1},{"value":"6.6","attribute_id":3,"id":7,"auction_id":1}]
```

Response:

```
"values.value":["can't be blank","must be an integer"]
```

Here, `can't be blank` error belongs to  first attribute, and `must be an integer` to second. So i need to write something like this in controller:

```
errors = @auction.errors.to_hash
errors['values'] = Hash[@auction.values.reject{ |v| v.valid? }.collect{ |v| [v.attribute_id, v.errors.to_hash]}]
```

to understand what the error belongs to which model.

Does it exist more clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have access to the exact error from a child record, you must not reach through the parent's errors collection. The child records themselves have a errors-collection where you can get detailed access. The aggregated error on the parent only illustrates that the record can't be saved because there are invalid child records.

If you need all errors you need to aggregate them yourself. (as you did with your `collect` call). If this code is used multiple times consider to move it into a method on `Auction`

```
class Auction
  def aggregated_errors
    errors = self.errors.to_hash
    errors['values'] = Hash[values.reject{ |v| v.valid? }.collect{ |v| [v.attribute_id, v.errors.to_hash]}]
    errors
  end
end
```

If you need to aggregate the errors of different models and associations you can further abstract the `collect` call to reuse it across models.